# Dealing with space in file path in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the below VBA code that I'm trying to run in `cmd`. There is a space in the path and I'm using quotes to deal with that.

```
strWot2Shell = """C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64.exe""" & " -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile=" & Chr(34) & ripDirectory & "\LagerRiskRapport%01d.png" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & filePathAndFileName & Chr(34)
strWot2Shell = Replace(strWot2Shell, "\", "/")
strWot2Shell2 = "cmd.exe /S /C " & strWot2Shell
wsh.Run strWot2Shell2, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

The output from the code as below:

```
cmd.exe /S /C "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.20/bin/gswin64.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile="G:/Rip/LagerRiskRapport%01d.png" "G:/LagerRiskRapport.pdf"
```

When I run this direclty in `cmd` I get:

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I run below directly in `cmd` it works

```
"C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.20/bin/gswin64.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile="G:/Rip/LagerRiskRapport%01d.png" "G:/LagerRiskRapport.pdf"
```

Triple quoting all string like this:

```
strWot2Shell = """C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64.exe""" & """ -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile=""" & Chr(34) & ripDirectory & """\LagerRiskRapport%01d.png""" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & filePathAndFileName & Chr(34)
```

Gives this output:

```
cmd.exe /S /C "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.20/bin/gswin64.exe"" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile=""G:/Rip"/LagerRiskRapport%01d.png"" "G:/LagerRiskRapport.pdf"
```

Surrounding `cmd.exe /S /C` in quotes like`"cmd.exe /S /C"` results in `The system cannot find the path specified`.

Why are the quotes not working?

Comment: How the output should look like to make it runnable? If you copy the VBA output and write it manually in the cmd, does it run OK?

Comment: @Vityata I've update the post. When I run `cmd.exe /S /C,,.` it doesn't work but runing just `C:/Progrmas,,.` works.

Comment: Can you try with this: `wsh.Run = "cmd.exe /S /C " & strWot2Shell, windowStyle, waitOnReturn`

Comment: @VityataI tried surrounding `cmd.exe` with quotes. It resulted in an error. I've updated the question with the result.

Comment: In the end I moved `gswin64.exe` to a path without a space in path.

Comment: Are you sure you need to replace backslashes with slashes? If you use cmd, most probably, backslash is the correct path separator.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are triple quoting at the beginning and then not at the end. So try changing this:

```
"""C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64.exe""" & " -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile=" & Chr(34) & ripDirectory & "\LagerRiskRapport%01d.png" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & filePathAndFileName & Chr(34)
```

To:

```
"""C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin64.exe""" & "" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile="" & Chr(34) & ripDirectory & ""\LagerRiskRapport%01d.png"" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & filePathAndFileName & Chr(34)
```

Comment: I gave that a try and it resulted on quotes in the string where there shouldn't be any quotes. I've updated the question with the result.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, it looks like it should be double quotes and not triple. I have updated my answer - see if this works.