# Can't get WSCript.Shell object's Run method to work

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I set up the following test procedure.

```vb
Private Sub TryPDF()
    
    Dim oShell          As Object
    Dim App             As String
    Dim SrcPath         As String
    Dim Fn              As String

    App = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe "
    SrcPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Downloads\"
    Fn = "20200509_Order_of_08_05_2020.PDF"

    Shell App & SrcPath & Fn, vbNormalFocus             ' opens the file
    
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
    oShell.Run App & SrcPath & Fn, vbNormalFocus, True  ' error -2147024894
    Set oShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

The Shell command in the middle works, thereby proving that app and files exist as and where specified. However, I want the `Wait` property of the `WSCript.Shell` object and therefore want to open the file using the line `oShell.Run App & SrcPath & Fn, vbNormalFocus, True`. I have tested it as shown and without some and any parameters, which should just open the Acrobat Reader when totally stripped, and I always get the same error, "Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Searching the error messages may find https://stackoverflow.com/q/41933387/9439330. Also debug.printing command and pasting to commandline may enlight you ;)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thank you for your time. Please enlighten me how your link relates to my question. The method you detail of "debug.printing command and pasting to commandline" seems enthralling but I'm not familiar with it. Which is the "command" in my case? If the "commandline" is the command prompt, I'm not aware of being able to paste to it. Can you give me a forecast of what I might expect to learn from that procedure?

Comment: As title of link says (I shouldn't have used bare url) "Dealing with space in file path in VBA" you have to escape them as they are used as argument separator on command-line. Use [Debug.Print](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) `App & SrcPath & Fn` to output command to immediate window (VBE), then copy and paste to cmd-line to test your command.

Comment: It can't be the space because (a) ` oShell.Run App` also fails and (b) `Shell App & SrcPath & Fn` works. However, meanwhile I found that `oShell.Run SrcPath & Fn`also works but `oShell.Run SrcPath & Fn, 1, True` doesn't wait for the app to finish. I suspect the oShell object not being quite what it's supposed to be.

Comment: `oShell.Run App` fails as blanks are in path to reader! `oShell.Run SrcPath & Fn` works as long as Adobe Reader is default PDF App! You removed `VBA.Shell` command as that open PDF first and then `WSCript.Shell` can't open it again and is finished.

Comment: So I learned that one can indeed paste to Cmd Prompt now. There I get the message :'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I'll take another look at your link.

Comment: I think you have put me on the right track. Thank you. But it'll take me a couple of hours to get there with lots of trial, error and research. If you post a proper answer I'll select it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the spaces in your paths (app and file) by surrounding them with double-Quotes, as the command-line uses them as argument separators. That would make

```vb
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe
```

`C.\Program` a file named Program located on C: and that doesn't exists!

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
```

will work as expected on command-line.

For some reasons [VBA.Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) can handle the spaces in the apppath, but [WScript.Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aew9yb99(v=vs.85)) can't.
Both will fail on not quoted paths to file, if they contain spaces.

My prefered quoting-style is the `Chr(34)` function

```vb
CommanQuoted = Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) 
 & "...\Downloads\20200509_Order_of_08_05_2020.PDF" & Chr(34)
```

as it is far better readable than the also useable double double-quote

```vb
CommandQuoted = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"" ""...\Downloads\20200509_Order_of_08_05_2020.PDF"""
```

Or you can create a constant that returns a double quote

```vb
Const dquote As String = """"
CommandQuoted = dquote & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" & dquote & " " & dquote 
 & "...\Downloads\20200509_Order_of_08_05_2020.PDF" & dquote
```

```vb
Private Sub OpenPDFWithWScripShell()
    Dim oShell          As Object
    Dim AppPathQuoted   As String
    Dim SrcPathQuoted   As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim shellCommand As String
    AppPathQuoted = Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" & Chr(34)
    FileName = "20200509_Order_of_08_05_2020.PDF"
    SrcPathQuoted = Chr(34) & Environ("UserProfile") & "\Downloads\" & FileName & Chr(34)
    shellCommand = AppPathQuoted & " " & SrcPathQuoted
    Debug.Print shellCommand
    
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
    oShell.Run shellCommand, vbNormalFocus, True
    Set oShell = Nothing
End Sub
```